# Displaying thumbnails as a grid

Tags: java, image, user-interface, layout

I have an application where I have to display images as thumbnails in a grid and when the users click on one of them , the original picture should be displayed in JAVA. I dont have an
idea as to how to display the thumbnails present in the folder in the form of grid. Any help as to how to start and some sample codes and links would be welcome.

Answer (score 6):

Work on one thing at a time.

1. Read about LayoutManagers and build a program that will lay out components in a grid.
2. Figure out how to read images and create a thumbnail. Add that to your program.
3. Mess with JDialog and creating popups.  Also look at Action classes and ActionListeners to tie creating a popup to a button click.

Comment: can you provide me with an example?

Comment: @ravi Stackoverflow way of things is not that we program for you. Ok I'am a full time developper, but maybe the main difference between you and me is I'll try first even if I don't know how to do it. I'll may end up googling what i don't know, open a few dozen (hundreds) blogs/tutorials/forums... Read the few that seems promising and go. It can be really fast, with pratice. So take confidence, get jzd advice as a start point, work a few hours on your problem by doing somes researchs (swing tutorials in particular) and come back if you are really stucK.

Answer (score 2):

Are you working in Swing? What part do you have problems with? If it's the layout, you can start with the [GridLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

Depending on how you want to implement the zoom, a [Frame](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) will be useful.

And to display the bitmaps, a [Label](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) will do.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a JComponent, you can try a [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). If you want a Layout, look at the [GridLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Nebula Gallery Widget](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/gallery/gallery.php) if you use SWT

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same requirement - and looked into using Flowlayout.  Unfortunately - as this page here describes - http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/ - it doesnt behave as we'd like.

Fortunately you can grab source for the 'WrapLayout' from the same page.

When it comes to loading images into your panel, for performance I recommend using a SwingWorker as explained here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#efficiency

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [JFlow](http://pwnt.be/lab/jflow/) it's not exactly what you were asking for but pretty close, and all done for you!